# For given two points in $B(0,r)$, construction of sphere inside $B(0,r)$

Tags: differential-geometry

We can construct a circle $C_1$ passing two given points $A,B$ inside a given circle $C$  such that $C_1$ touches $C$. My claim is that,it is true for the higher dimensional case that is, one can construct a sphere inside $B(0,r)$ that passes through two points $a,b\in B(0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Is this true? If true then how it will be constructed?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the 2-dimensional construction in the plane containing $a$, $b$ and $0$, which gives you a circle centred on some point $p$ with radius $r'$ passing through $a,b$, and consider the sphere $\partial B(p,r')$ which contains this as a great circle. Clearly the sphere contains $a,b$, and since the circle stays inside $B(0,r)$ we must have $|p|+r' \le r$, so the whole sphere stays inside $B(0,r)$.